# Bad address received from recvfrom: why?

Tags: c, sockets, pointers, recvfrom

I'm writing a function that is supposed to do some operations and then return (using its arguments) the address of the device that is interacting with (i.e. that used `sendto`) the `recvfrom` inside the function.

Here's how I call the function, instantiating `cliaddr` before.

```
struct sockaddr_in cliaddr;
memset((void *) &cliaddr, 0, sizeof(cliaddr));
rcv_string(sockfd, &return_string, &cliaddr);
// Here I'll need to use cliaddr, that's why I need it outside too
```

Here's the implementation of the function:

```
int rcv_string(int sockfd, char **return_string, struct sockaddr_in *sndaddr) {
    // ...
    char buff[PACKETSZ + 2];
    memset(&buff, 0, sizeof(buff)); // Clean buffer
    socklen_t *plen = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr *));
    if ((recvfrom(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *) sndaddr, plen)) < 0) {
            perror("recvfrom");
            return -1;
    }
    char *snd_ip = malloc(INET_ADDRSTRLEN * sizeof(char));
    if (inet_ntop(AF_INET, &((*sndaddr).sin_addr.s_addr), snd_ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN * sizeof(char)) == NULL) {
            perror("inet_ntop");
            return -1;
    }
    printf("Received '%s' from '%s'.\n", buff, snd_ip);
    // ...
}
```

Now, even if the ip address of the sending device is `192.168.1.251` I get the following output:

```
Received '0packetx' from '0.0.0.0'.
```

The received buffer is formatted correctly, but the address is evidently wrong. Why? Does it have to do with the definition of the address variable outside the function?

#### EDIT

If after the `memset` of `cliaddr` I add also those 3 lines:

```
cliaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
cliaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
cliaddr.sin_port = htons(SERV_PORT);
```

I get a random behavior. Sometimes I get `0.0.0.0`, sometimes `127.0.0.1` and sometimes the correct address (`192.168.1.251`).

Comment: Minor: `(*sndaddr).sin_addr` = `sndaddr->sin_addr`

Comment: Just because you have functions that accept pointer arguments does not mean you need to use dynamic memory allocation.  Often you don't.  Instead, use the address-of operator (`&`) when you can to create a pointer to an ordinary object of the appropriate type.  Or sometimes it's appropriate to use an array.

Comment: Thank you both @EugeneSh. and  @JohnBollinger for your comments. I'll try to follow you hints from now on. Do you have any idea on why I get `0.0.0.0`? It really puzzles me. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are passing the wrong length to recvfrom

```
  socklen_t *plen = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr *));
    if ((recvfrom(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *) sndaddr, plen))
```

Why you malloc is a mystery, but you need

```
socklen_t *plen = malloc(sizeof(socklen_t));
*plen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in );
```

much simpler is

```
      socklen_t plen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
   if ((recvfrom(sockfd, buff, sizeof(buff), 0, (struct sockaddr *) sndaddr, &plen))
```

Comment: I'm surprised this issue hasn't received more attention. I've been stuck on this for days and after reading this, I realized that all 3 of the sources I used as examples for `recvfrom` were wrong! None of them initialized the actual length of a `sockaddr_in`! The sneaky thing is, not doing this will still work about 50% of the time and the payload arrives seemingly always intact.

Answer (score -3):

It should work if you fill plen with valid sizeof data.

```
*plen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
```

You can put that right before the recvfrom call.

Comment: You are right, thanks for the answer: I fixed it, but the wrong ip issue is not solved of course.